# Make Akka guardian actor use custom dispatcher

Tags: scala, akka, akka-typed, akka-dispatcher

I have defined a custom dispatcher in application.conf like this:

```
my-special-dispatcher {
  type = Dispatcher
  executor = "thread-pool-executor"
  thread-pool-executor {
    fixed-pool-size = 1
  }
  throughput = 1
}
```

The documentation says to create an actor using a custom dispatcher like this:

```scala
context
  .spawn(
    yourBehavior, 
    "DispatcherFromConfig", 
    DispatcherSelector.fromConfig("your-dispatcher")
  )
```

However, I want to use this custom dispatcher for the guardian actor, which is not created via `context.spawn`.

I currently create my actor system and guardian actor like this:

```scala
implicit val myActorSystem: ActorSystem[MyGuardianActor.Request] = {
  ActorSystem[MyGuardianActor.Request](
    MyGuardianActor(), 
    name = "MyGuardianActorSingleton"
  )
```

How would I modify this to use my custom dispatcher called "my-special-dispatcher"?

Note: I only want to use the custom dispatcher for the guardian actor.  All other actors in the system should use the default dispatcher.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the [ActorSystem class](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.8/akka/actor/typed/ActorSystem.html) which is what you get when you use the `apply` method from the [ActorSystem companion object](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.8/akka/actor/typed/ActorSystem$.html). In your case, you are using the one that only [receives the user guardian actor and the name of the actor system](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.8/akka/actor/typed/ActorSystem$.html#apply%5BT%5D(guardianBehavior:akka.actor.typed.Behavior%5BT%5D,name:String):akka.actor.typed.ActorSystem%5BT%5D)

```scala
def apply[T](
  guardianBehavior: Behavior[T], 
  name: String
): ActorSystem[T]
```

The factory method that lets you set a dispatcher for the guardian actor is [this one](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.8/akka/actor/typed/ActorSystem$.html#apply%5BT%5D(guardianBehavior:akka.actor.typed.Behavior%5BT%5D,name:String,config:com.typesafe.config.Config,guardianProps:akka.actor.typed.Props):akka.actor.typed.ActorSystem%5BT%5D)

```scala
def apply[T](
  guardianBehavior: Behavior[T], 
  name: String, 
  config: Config, 
  guardianProps: Props
): ActorSystem[T]
```

As you can see, the last param lets you set the dispatcher like you can do when you spawn childs. Doing something like the following example should work for you

```scala
val dispatcherSelector = DispatcherSelector.fromConfig("my-special-dispatcher")

ActorSystem[MyGuardianActor.Request](
  guardianBehavior = MyGuardianActor(), 
  name = "MyGuardianActorSingleton",
  config = ConfigFactory.load(),
  guardianProps = dispatcherSelector
)
```